# Flutter Inspector is looking weird

Tags: android, flutter, inspector

I am using Android Studio 4.1.3 and the flutter inspector is showing like zoomed in. How can I fix this?? [Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wElyJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The following steps helped me to get Flutter Inspector look normal, hopefully, it will help you as well:

1. File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter:
2. Disable (Uncheck) {Experiments: "Enable embedding DevTools in the Flutter Inspector tool window"}
3. Stop and start the app again.

Note: In order for something to show up in the Flutter Inspector, your app has to be running on a Device or on a Simulator or Emulator.